# How to detect path the file(whether playing from internal or URL stream) being played in Android?

Tags: java, android

I have a programmed a custom exoplayer videoview to play videos from both internal memory and URL's. Now i want to check whether the video that is played presently in Videoview is from URL Stream or Internal storage. How can i check this?

Comment: Track it yourself. You were the one who told ExoPlayer what to play. In addition to calling the ExoPlayer methods to begin playback, also hold onto that information in a field of some class somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two methods to determine whether it's internal or remote.

#### Method 1 - Using `Uri`

Parse the given URI using `Uri.parse(...)` then use [`getScheme()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#getScheme()) to get the scheme. For (internal) files it will be `file`.

For example:

```
String file = "file:///path/of/your/file";
String remote = "https://www.example.com/your_video.mp4";

Uri fileUri = Uri.parse(file);
Uri remoteUri = Uri.parse(remote);

String fileScheme = fileUri.getScheme();
String remoteScheme = remoteUri.getScheme();

Log.d("Scheme", fileScheme); // prints file
Log.d("Scheme", remoteScheme); // prints https
```

#### Method 2 - Using `File`

Create a new `File` instance from the URI and check if it exists.

For example:

```
String file = "file:///path/of/your/file";
String remote = "https://www.example.com/your_video.mp4";

File fileFile = new File(file);
File remoteFile = new File(remote);

Log.d("File", "" + fileFile.exists()); // prints true if the file exists
Log.d("File", "" + remoteFile.exists()); // prints false always
```